# Java - Two variables in the same System.out.println

Tags: java

I need to put 2 variables in the same System.out.println, what's wrong with this code?

I have these errors every time I try to put two variables in the same system.out.println, so I always end separating them in several lines

```
//ejercicio 6
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mayor{

public static void main (String [] args){

Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Introduzca 3 numeros distintos a continuación");
Double uno = In.nextDouble();
Double dos = In.nextDouble();
Double tres = In.nextDouble();

  if (uno>dos && dos>tres){
  System.out.println(+ uno " sería el mayor y " + tres" el menor");
  }else

  if (dos>tres && tres>uno){
  System.out.println(+ dos " sería el mayor y " + uno" el menor");
  }else

  if (tres>uno && uno>dos){
  System.out.println(+ tres " sería el mayor y " + dos" el menor");
 }
}
}
```

I keep getting these errors

```
mayor.java:24: ')' expected
  System.out.println(+ tres " sería el mayor y " + dos" el menor");
                           ^
mayor.java:24: not a statement
  System.out.println(+ tres " sería el mayor y " + dos" el menor");
                                                 ^
mayor.java:24: ';' expected
  System.out.println(+ tres " sería el mayor y " + dos" el menor");
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `+ tres " ...` would do? Please read the most basic of Java tutorials.

Comment: "tres" is a variable.. i didn't put all the code. Sorry, my language is spanish

Comment: @DanielArocha: Sotirios isn't commenting on your English. He's commmenting on your *Java*.

Answer (score 2):

You made a syntax error with the + sign.

```
System.out.println( tres + " sería el mayor y " + dos + " el menor");
```

Assuming `tres` and `dos` are variables.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `+` [operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) is used to concatenate strings. If one argument is a `String`, and one is not, Java will call the `.toString()` method of the Object that is not already string. If it's a primitive type, it will be wrapped in its respective wrapper class before callint `toString`.

`+` is a binary operator, therefore it requires **two** arguments. (there is a unary `+`, too, but that one isn't valid on `String`s or any other object).

Therefore, assuming `tres` and `dos` are defined, you can concatenate their string representations with your other string using binary (not unary) `+`:

```
System.out.println( tres + " sería el mayor y " + dos + " el menor");
```

Comment: Thanks to all, ready :)

Answer (score 0):

It will look like this:

```
int tres = 3;
int dos = 2;

System.out.println(tres + " sería el mayor y " +  dos + " el menor");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need.

`System.out.println(tres + " sería el mayor y " + dos + " el menor");`

Answer (score 0):

Try it out with:

```
System.out.println(tres + " sería el mayor y " dos + " el menor");
```

Answer (score 0):

The stuff inside the brackets of the `println` call  is not a well formed expression.  What you should have is a sequences of strings and / or values that can be converted to strings, with the binary `+` (string concatenation) operator between each pair of them; e.g.

```
System.out.println(tres + " sería el mayor y " + dos + " el menor");
```

What you have written is analogous to writing the sum `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` as `+ 1 2 + 3 4`.  It is not valid Java, and the Java compiler is simply telling you what it was *expecting* to see at the indicated point.